# Prove that a doubly stochastic matrix is a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix denoted by $(a_{ij})_{m \times n}$  is said to be doubly stochastic if:

$$ \sum_{i}{a_{ij}} = \sum_{j}{a_{ij}} = 1 $$

I am trying to prove that such a matrix is a square matrix. I thought of multiplying or adding 2 of such matrices together but this leads to nowhere. I also wrote down down a generalised doubly stochastic matrix in this form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I can't see any relationship between the different rows and columns from this form. Could anyone please give me some hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the sum of rows is $1$ and there are $n$ rows then the sum of all entries is $n$
similarly the sum of column entries is also $1$ and suppose that there are $m$ columns then the sum of matrix entries is $m$
but the matrix sum is invariant.
  Hence $m=n$